# In Java regex - how to retain numbers ONLY when attached to string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to tokenize text files that contain useful text but also many numbers that I don't want. However, using something like `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`, I retain all digits `(0-9)`.

I would like to retain digits ONLY if attached to characters OR hypnenated like "24hr" or "7-days".

So, input: "There are 3, 24hr positions available 7-days a week. Call 555-1212"

Returns a list of the following tokens: There are 24hr positions available 7-days a week Call

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What about a string like `foo-bar-`, what tokes should match there? What about `-7` or `-7x`?

Comment: 'foo-bar-' should parse on the two '-'s leving 'foo' and 'bar'. '-7' should be gone altogether and -7x' should return '7x'.
I should clarify, I want to select everything BUT the words. So, just the opposite of the bottom two answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of trial and error, this did it (note leading space):

```
     \d[^-a-z]+ | -\d+|[^a-zA-Z0-9-]|[0-9]+-[0-9]+|\W-+|[0-9]+-\W
```

http://regexr.com?318hp
I hope this helps anyone else who needs it.
I'm using it in RapidMiner to remove unwanted tokens in text processing.

Answer (score 3):

```
\d+-?[A-Za-z]+|[A-Za-z]+-?\d+|[A-Za-z]+
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?318em

Comment: How can I take just the opposite of the result? For the purpose of extracting text tokens, I need to retain the output tokens by parsing based on unwanted characters. Basically, I need just the opposite of above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Warning**: Don't use `A-z`. Check your local ASCII table to see what that range includes. Instead you can use `[a-zA-Z]` or `(?i)[a-z]` or `[a-z]` with `i` flag enabled in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets `[`, `]` represent something called a character class, which basically means match anything in this class. `[A-Za-z0-9]` will match any combination of letters and digits.

If you want to specify order you need to remove the digits from the character class and add another character class after it.

ex:

```
[0-9]+-?[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+-?[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+

[a-zA-Z]+ - matches 1 or more letters
-?        - optionally matches a dash
[0-9]+    - matches 1 or more digits
```

Comment: Hunter, thanks for the explanation. That helps a lot. Is it possible to return the opposite of the above? In other words, I'm trying to break the sentence apart by selecting all the areas I want to discard?

Comment: @zbinsd I am not sure that it will work in this scenario, but generally you can use something called a negative lookahead of the form `(?!<Your_Regex_Here>)`